# How to exclude a specific device brand/model when it is not shown in Google Play Console Device Catalog?

Tags: android, device, google-play-console, catalog, restrict

I'm trying to exclude the following device brand/model as this is not compatible with my app:

```
Brand: Trend
Model: TaintArt for x86
```

However, though this device appears continuously in my Crashlytics report, I cannot find it in the Device Catalog, so I cannot exclude/restrict it.

The following is an image from Crashlytics report:
[image]

Navigation to Device Catalog:

```
1. Login to Google Play Console
2. Select app
3. Release Management
4. Device Catalog
5. Search for Device (Trend, Taintart, etc.)
6. Result: 0 match your criteria
```

[image]

Is there any other way to exclude this brand/model ?

Edit (3/27/2020): Same issue with "Batmobile Defy Mini", which is always crashing due to a strange error caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException when inflating class.

Answer (score 0):

It has appeared in my crashlogs, as well, with the exact same Android version and root state. When searching Google for it, I came across a disassembling project. Possibly someone is using this to get to your app's code. It doesn't seem to be an official device hence sadly it cannot be excluded, at least not in the device catalogue. Sorry :(

Comment: Yes, this is what I suspect. It is clearly using an apk downloaded from a third party website. I know this because the crashes are related to the fact that it is using a non-split APK (which is generating "file not found" errors when trying to use some specific drawables). Looks like the only way to avoid the crash is by catching the error and showing an alert like "Not a genuine copy. Download the app from playstore".

Comment: That would at least help you to get rid of the error. In my case, I've also noticed other crashes on other rooted devices just a couple of minutes later. I don't think that's a coincidence, so I guess that the person could also be the cause of more similar crashes but on other devices.

Comment: What is the error message shown in Crashlytics in your case?

Comment: They couldn't inflate a Button (InflateException) because certain resources weren't found which led to failing at starting an activity (RuntimeException). The devices were pretty wide spread and one strangely had more than 24 GB of RAM.

Comment: Yes, I had the same InflateException issue. In my case, it is happening when an APK is used without the "split" functionality provided by Google. So, if you defined multiple drawables for same object (one for xdpi, one for hdpi, mdpi etc.), the crash seems to appear when this device (or the APK) tries to open the drawable. Probably, it is just looking for a "generic" object (which does not exist) instead of looking for the one specified according to the right resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this device, it looks like it is a bot from this company:

> [Trend Micro](https://mars.trendmicro.com/) Mobile App Reputation Service or MARS is a
> cloud-based service that automatically identifies mobile threats based
> on app behaviors.